# Notepad++ and autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I'm using mainly **[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)** for my C++ developing and recently i'm in need for some kind of *basic autocompletion*, nothing fuzzy, just want to type some letters and get my **function declaration** instead of having a manual opened all of the time..

The integrated autocompletion feature of my Notepad++ version (6.9.2) gives the declaration of basic C functionality like say **[fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen)** and parses my *current file* user defined functions, but without declaration.

I guess it's normal for a text editor to not give easily such information since it has nothing to parse i.e. other files where your declarations are (as it's not an IDE), but i don't want either to mess again with MSVC just for the sake of autocomplete.

Is there an easy, not so-hackish way to add some basic C++ and/or user defined autocomplete?

**UPDATE**

Adding declarations the "hard way" in some file **cpp.xml** is a no-no for me as i have a pretty big base of ever changing declarations. Is there a way to just input say some list of *h/cpp* files and get declarations? or this falls into *custom plugin* area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the ***cpp.xml*** file and add all the keywords and function descriptions you'd like.  Just make sure you add them in alphabetical order or they will not show up.

Another option is to select ***Function and word completion*** in the ***Auto-Completion*** area of the ***Settings-->Preferences*** dialog.  NPP will suggest every "word" in the current file that starts with the first N letters you type (you choose a value for N in the Auto-Completion controls).

Comment: I see.. so there isn't a way without having to hard type them in a file? I have a rather large base of used defined functions of ever changing declarations and structs...  I updated my question

Comment: @user6096479 A 3rd way is to write a script or program that will parse a set of files and generate cpp.xml for you (you'd have to manually run the script or program every so often to keep things updated).  This is what I've done to generate C.xml when I am doing UEFI programming.

Comment: funny thing is that i already have my PHP doing an automatic manual generation on the fly out of _C/C++_ files. Perhaps that's the best solution,  i'm just going to switch from HTML generation into XML generation for this case. Thanx!